# Android ListView display a single array into 2 columns

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I have a single array like ABCD and I want to display it in two columns using `ListView` like

A B

C D

onClick event should return the position in the array.
Rather avoid to use 2 separate `ListView`.

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: **Welcome to Stack Overflow**, StackOverflow is neither a forum, tutorial site nor web search replacement. We can [**help with certain problems**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but it's your job to [**put some efforts**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) in the first place, including elementary [**(re)search**](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=KlC2WdDPCKzT8gfFz72QDw). Read [**how to ask perfect question**](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: u are probably going to be voted down, but i understand u r beginner, so u could use a grid, or table with custom adapter.

Comment: So far I can see only samples with an array bind to each column, looking for  one array displayed on 2 columns.

Comment: another idea: use usual list, with a custom row layout with 2 column,  for the data set, the first row is A&B, 2nd row is C & D. If you wan to have independent vertical scroll, then it is a different story

Comment: I tried that splitting my array in odd and even and display in 2 column adaptor, but run in trouble to differentiate onClick event

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `ListView` you can use `GridView` with maximum columns 2.
set the `ArrayList` using Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You should use RecyclerView because it support Grid Functionality which you want to achieve using GridLayoutManager

Comment: I don't have so much data, just one array as a shopping list which I like to display into 2 columns

Comment: then just follow what @NikhilSawant mentioned, that the logical solution